# Why are some Yang Zhang constant k different from the original paper?

Tags: volatility

I've seen this in the original paper ([Yang, Zhang: Drift Independent Volatility Estimation ...](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.628.4037&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) (see Equation 10, Page 483)

$$k = \frac{\alpha - 1 }{\alpha + \frac{ n + 1 }{ n - 1 }}$$

while there are some implementations with this (in [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.23-2/topics/volatility))

$$k =\frac{\alpha}{1 + \frac{ n + 1}{n - 1 } }$$

Why the difference ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Where does the second formula come from?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.23-2/topics/volatility

Comment: Please check the math @JohnStephen.19

Comment: I tried substituting a = 1.34 and n = 30. They're not the same